# How to make a function linear

Tags: functions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

I have a linear function, say `f`, and an expression like `f[3x^2 - 8 a y^2 + 4 z b]` where I know that `a` and `b` are real constants. I would like to make some substitution which gives `3f[x^2]-8a f[y^2]+4bf[z]`, i.e. specifying which constants to pull out of the argument of `f`. Something a little like

`Map[f, 3x^2 - 8 a y^2 + 4z b]` --> `f[3x^2] + f[-8 a y^2] + f[4z b]`

but also with constants taken out. All the ways I can think of to do this are very messy: is there a built in method for this?

Comment: It looks like your "linear function" can be no more complicated that multiplication by a constant.  Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Try `Distribute[f[3 x^2 - 8 a y^2 + 4 z b]] /. f[expr_] :> (#1 f[#2] & @@ FactorTermsList[expr])`.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon, this gives ``3 f[x^2] - 8 f[a y^2] + 4 f[b z]``, but I want to specify that a and b are also real numbers in order to get ``3f[x^2]-8a f[y^2]+4bf[z]``

Comment: @mikado, I'm not saying that ``f[x^2]=f[x]x``, just that ``f[ax]=af[x]``. In my Mathematica notebook, ``f[expr]`` actually denotes integration of ``expr*(other stuff)`` over `y` and `z` ,  and `a` and `b` are independent of the integration variables. Apologies if I am explaining this badly.

Comment: `expr //. {x^k_. :> f[x^k], y^m_. :> f[y^m], z^n_. :> f[z^n]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define something like the following

```
numberq[_] := False
numberq[_?NumericQ] := True
f[u_Plus] := f /@ u
f[a_?numberq x_] := a f[x]
```

You then specify that `a` and `b` are to be treated as numeric constants

```
numberq[a | b] = True;
```

You then get the simplification you requested

```
f[3 x^2 - 8 a y^2 + 4 z b]
(* 3 f[x^2] - 8 a f[y^2] + 4 b f[z] *)
```